# Race countdown widget

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm new to python and I really hope for some help.

I am trying to create an app for an automatic slot car lap count/timer.
I need some kind of count down before the race starts, and I am using a QLabel  for this.

I want to update this with the 'update_label()' function, but it does not seems to work.
What did I do wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import sys, time
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QPushButton, QLabel, QLineEdit, QGridLayout, QApplication, QLCDNumber, QSlider
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication, Qt



class race(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):

        lane1 = QLabel('READY?')

        grid = QGridLayout()
        grid.setSpacing(10)

        grid.addWidget(lane1, 1, 0, 1, 1)

        self.setLayout(grid)


        self.setGeometry(400, 300, 600, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('Race')
        self.showMaximized()

        self.update_label()

    def update_label(self):
        count = 3
        while count>1:
            time.sleep(1)
            counter = count

            Label = self.lane1.setText(counter)
            timer = QtCore.QTimer()      
            timer.timeout.connect(Label)
            timer.start(10000)

            count = count - 1



if __name__ == '__main__':

    raceApp = QApplication(sys.argv)
    racePanel = race()
    sys.exit(raceApp.exec_())
```

But this error is thrown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./race.py", line 58, in <module>
    racePanel = race()
  File "./race.py", line 16, in __init__
    self.initUI()
  File "./race.py", line 35, in initUI
    self.update_label()
  File "./race.py", line 45, in update_label
    Label = self.lane1.setText(counter)
AttributeError: 'race' object has no attribute 'lane1'
```

Comment: @CroMagnon I approved your edit. When editing, please also remove signature lines, "Thanks", etc. These are considered noise. See ["Should Hi, Thanks, Taglines and salutations be removed from posts"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)  for more information.

Comment: timer.timeout.connect should connect to a slot (a callable in python), Label is whatever setText returns, probably void. This is not a callable. Please read more about signals and slots in Qt and probably also about Python in general.

Answer (score 0):

Sir, your code is a mess hahaha.. This error that is occurring is because you don't have this label in the method bellow, it should be declared as "self." so it would be global and you'd have access to it.

There are many other weird things in the way you are defining things.

Have some tips:

1. Have a look in python [API](https://docs.python.org/3.5/c-api/).
2. Have also a look in [Qt API](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/classes.html)
3. **DOWNLOAD SOME SIMPLE CODE EXAMPLES AND HAVE A LOOK IN HOW THINGS WORK :D**. For example [here](http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt4/). You just have to change your imports to PyQt5 if you prefer.

Anyways,

**Try something like this. I made some modifications...**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import sys, time

from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget,  QLabel, QGridLayout, QApplication



class race(QWidget):
    lane1 = None

    timer = None

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):

        self.lane1 = QLabel('READY?')

        self.timer = QTimer()

        self.grid = QGridLayout()
        self.grid.setSpacing(10)

        self.grid.addWidget(self.lane1, 1, 0, 1, 1)

        self.setLayout(self.grid)


        self.setGeometry(400, 300, 600, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('Race')
        self.showMaximized()

        self.update_label()

    def update_label(self):



        self.timer.start(99999999)
        self.timer.setInterval(999999)
        self.lane1.setText(str(self.timer.remainingTime()))

    def paintEvent(self, q_painter_event):
        self.lane1.setText(str(self.timer.remainingTime()))
        super(race, self).paintEvent(q_painter_event)



if __name__ == '__main__':

    raceApp = QApplication(sys.argv)
    racePanel = race()
    sys.exit(raceApp.exec_())
```

***You just gotta adapt to what you want :p***